# bind click event to the element in ng-repeat angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have menu and use `ng-repeat` for loop to the my category and in this loop i have a link tag and I want to when clicked on this link do something in js file.
But I can't access to the tag a in javascript and add click event to this element.

**Here is my ng-repeat code:**

```
<li class="has-children" ng-repeat="category in categories  |filter:{ level: 1 } : true" ng-if="$index < 5">
    <a class="parent-link">{{category.categoryName}}</a>
    <ul class="is-hidden">
        <li class="go-back"><a>{{category.categoryName}}</a></li>
        <li ng-repeat="submenu in categories |filter:{ parentID: category.categoryID } : true"><a>{{submenu.categoryName}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here is my js file (this code doesn't fire):

```
$(".parent-link").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log("clicked");
  e.prenvetDefault()
});
```

Comment: if you are using Angular JS, why not use `ng-click`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-click`. It can be used as attribute of element. Example usage:

HTML:

```
<div ng-click="changeWord()">
   {{word}}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.changeWord = function () {
    $scope.word = 'I am changed';
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ax6k3z1e/

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason could be that you Javascript is getting executed before the DOM is ready.  You should use `ng-click` as It's good to build through Angular way when you are using AngularJS in you application.

Answer (score 0):

ng-Repeat have the tendency to bind your iterating object as well. Below is the example for the same.

```
<div ng-repeat='ele in elements'>
<p ng-click='ShowAlert(ele)'>{{ele.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Specify below mentioned code in your linked controller.

```
$scope.ShowAlert=function(element){
alert(element.Name);
}
```